# Radiogroup setOnCheckedChanged ids issues

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I was trying to check if a radiobutton was either checked or not and do some stuff in consequence when I found this weird behaviour which I can't understand. I must say the radiogroup is inside a PreferenceDialog which is my only explanation for the problem.

```
RadioGroup colorRG = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.colorRG);

         colorRG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    Log.w("ColorRG: ", "checkedId" + checkedId);
                    if (checkedId == (R.id.color_box1)){
                        Log.d("ColorRG: ","first if");
                        }
                    if (checkedId == (R.id.color_box1+5)){
                        Log.d("ColorRG: ","second if");
                        }
                    }
                 });
```

Well, the Log shows that the checkedId value is 2131165319 and R.id.color_box1 has a value of 2131165314. Obviously, it doesn't enter the first if. It shows the second if log.

So, what happening here?

I hope someone can help

EDIT: Adding xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/color_box1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/selector_descript"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_selector_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/color_box2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/selector_descript"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_selector_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/color_box3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/selector_descript"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_selector_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/color_box4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/selector_descript"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_selector_color" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/colorRG"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/color_radio1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/selector_RB1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/color_radio2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/selector_RB2" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/color_radio3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/selector_RB3" />

         <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/color_radio4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/selector_RB4" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/pincancel_but"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@string/cancelar" />

         <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"     
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pinok_but"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This wrong way "R.id.color_box1+5" check id.

Comment: can you please post your xml where you define RadioButton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it will help you

```
RadioGroup colorRG = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.colorRG);    


colorRG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup,
            int radioButtonID) {

if(radioButtonID==colorRg.getCheckedRadioButtonId)
{
Log.i("tt","firstlog"+radioButtonID);//you will get id now
}
             }
    }
});
```

Comment: Still the same... radioBtnID value is 2131165314 while radioButtonID value keeps 2131165319

Comment: I'll try it in a while and I'll tell you about

Comment: k i'll wait, once you complete let me know

Comment: I've tried the code and isn't working... it's just the same issue >.<

Comment: It is not showing the log, still the same values of id

Comment: try my updated answer now you will get the log and current id of the radio button

Comment: That's why I opened this question, I don't know why, but I can´t get it done... Maybe having <View/>s inside my Radiogroup is making this happen?

Comment: I cannot change them, there are 5 views there I'm using for gui style purposes

Comment: just check the above code for three radio button under one radiogroup if its worked means then try for your 5 views, because i'm tried and it worked me dude

Comment: seem to be working now, I don't really now what i've changed; thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

this is not the correct way

```
checkedId == (R.id.color_box1+5)
```

because `id` is **Auto-generated** field `R.java` which is generated automatically.`You can not create id like that.`
So, change the `id` of second `radio button` in `xml` file. Suppose you give the id is

```
android:id="@+id/color_box5"
```

JAVA code will be

```
colorRG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    Log.w("ColorRG: ", "checkedId" + checkedId);
                    if (checkedId == (R.id.color_box1)){
                        Log.d("ColorRG: ","first if");
                        }
                    if (checkedId == (R.id.color_box5)){
                        Log.d("ColorRG: ","second if");
                        }
                    }
                 });
```

This will work for you.

Comment: The id you are suggesting is the one I'm already using; "R.id.color_box1+5" doesn't mean I'm trying to use "color_box1+5" as an id. It means I need to add 5 to my id in order to make that work